# Oracle: FROM keyword not found where expected error in select statment

Tags: oracle

I am getting below error in my function.

Error:  `FROM keyword not found where expected`

And here is my Function:

```
    private int BauteilLieferzeit(string Materianummer)
    {
        try
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
                " Select MATNR, AVG_DAUER" +
                " AVG " +
                    " (DATEDIFF " +
                        " (mi, Z.APL_ANFDATUM, " +
                        " Z.STA_LIEFERDATUM)) " +
                " as AVG_DAUER " +
                " from ZDATA AS Z " +
                " where MATNR = '" + Materianummer + "'" 
                        , OraVerbindung._conn);


            OracleDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (r.HasRows)
            {
                int Restminuten = OraVerbindung.Lieferzeit;
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    Restminuten = r.GetInt32(1);
                }
                return Restminuten;
            }
            else
            {
                return OraVerbindung.Lieferzeit;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return OraVerbindung.Lieferzeit;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Missing a comma in the statement before AVG

Comment: is `AVG_DAUER` a column in the table or calculated in the query? Note, that you have two columns with this name in the query.

Comment: Really hate to see the down voting on new users, who offer a complete and clear question, but just had a little struggle with the basics of things. We should not down vote based on the level of coding skills, in this case maybe a skilled Java developer just new at SQL.

Comment: huh - maybe not Java ... `catch` does not specify an exception, lowercase 's' in `string`, and slightly unfamiliar naming convention. Please make sure your posting is first tagged with the implementing programming language, all other tags follow.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle this is not a valid syntax

```
from ZDATA AS Z
```

use

```
 from ZDATA Z
```

instead (remove "AS")

Additionally consider the use of bind variables instead of string concatenation:

```
 " where MATNR = '" + Materianummer + "'"
```

- search for "SQL Injection".

Comment: This is an issue too. But the `FROM keyword not found where expected` error is due to missing comma.

Comment: Good to bring up the SQL Injection issue. It is a cause for bugs, backdoors, and performance issues. Very persistent bugger too, people just don't want to drop the concatenation for binding.

Comment: Yes i know about this injection, i chanche it later

Comment: I chanche what you have wrote, now it com the error:" ORA 00904:\DATEDIFF\

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Included the issue highlighted by Marmite also. But the error `FROM keyword not found where expected` would be due to missing comma in select statement.

Edit: Removed `AVG_DAUER` column as it is getting derived later.

```
private int BauteilLieferzeit(string Materianummer)
{
    try
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
            " Select MATNR," +
            " AVG " +
                " (DATEDIFF " +
                    " (mi, Z.APL_ANFDATUM, " +
                    " Z.STA_LIEFERDATUM)) " +
            " as AVG_DAUER " +
            " from ZDATA Z " +
            " where MATNR = '" + Materianummer + "'" 
                    , OraVerbindung._conn);


        OracleDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (r.HasRows)
        {
            int Restminuten = OraVerbindung.Lieferzeit;
            while (r.Read())
            {
                Restminuten = r.GetInt32(1);
            }
            return Restminuten;
        }
        else
        {
            return OraVerbindung.Lieferzeit;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return OraVerbindung.Lieferzeit;
    }


}
```